# Why the result by hand is different from the built-in DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

Yesterday, I used *Mathematica* to solve a differential equation using the *built-in* command `DSolve[]`:

```
DSolve[y''[x] + 2 y'[x] + 5 y[x] == x Cos[x], y[x], x]
```

> ```
> {{y[x] -> 
>      E^-x C[2] Cos[2 x] + E^-x C[1] Sin[2 x] 
>    + 1/200 (-25 Cos[x] Cos[2 x] + 25 x Cos[x] Cos[2 x] 
>    - 3 Cos[2 x] Cos[3 x] + 15 x Cos[2 x] Cos[3 x]  
>    - 25 x Cos[2 x] Sin[x] + 25 x Cos[x] Sin[2 x] 
>    + 4 Cos[3 x] Sin[2 x] + 5 x Cos[3 x] Sin[2 x] 
>    - 25 Sin[x] Sin[2 x] + 25 x Sin[x] Sin[2 x]
>    - 4 Cos[2 x] Sin[3 x] - 5 x Cos[2 x] Sin[3 x]
>    - 3 Sin[2 x] Sin[3 x] + 15 x Sin[2 x] Sin[3 x])}}
> ```

However, I felt the result is too complex. So I calculate it by hand as shown below.

*Characteristic equation*:  $r^2+2r+5=0 \Rightarrow r_1 = -1 + 2i, r_2 = -1 - i$

So the `Non-homogeneous equation` general solution is:$e^{-x}(C_1 \cos(2x)+C_2 \sin(2x))$

I use the **Differential Operator** method to calculate the non-homogeneous particular solution:

[image: Differential Operator method]

So my question is why the two results are different? Can someone tell me the reason?

Comment: If you simplify M answer, then it becomes: `Simplify[%]; y[x] -> 1/50 E^-x (50 C[2] Cos[2 x] + E^x (-1 + 5 x) Sin[x] +Cos[x] (E^x (-7 + 10 x) + 100 C[1] Sin[x]))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are the same answer, as verified below. You can use the `Simplify` command to simplify things if needed:

```
mma = y[x] /. First@DSolve[y''[x] + 2 y'[x] + 5 y[x] == x Cos[x], y[x], x];
handH = E^(-x)*(C[2] Cos[2 x] + C[1] Sin[2 x]);
handP = (1/5 x - 7/50) Cos[x] + (1/10 x - 1/50) Sin[x];
hand = handH + handP;
Simplify[mma - hand]
```

and the answer is

```
                                0
```

QED

Answer (score 2):

One could also feed the ODE into `DifferentialRoot[]` (along with arbitrary initial conditions) and then apply `FunctionExpand[]`.

```
sol = FunctionExpand[DifferentialRoot[Function[{y, x},
                                               {y''[x] + 2 y'[x] + 5 y[x] == x Cos[x], 
                                                y[0] == C[1], y'[0] == C[2]}]][x]];
```

Some trickery with `Collect[]` then displays a solution qualitatively similar to the one derived by hand:

```
Collect[sol, _Cos | _Sin, Simplify]
   (-7/50 + x/5) Cos[x] + 1/50 E^-x (7 + 50 C[1]) Cos[2 x] + 
   1/50 (-1 + 5 x) Sin[x] + 1/50 E^-x (-1 + 25 C[1] + 25 C[2]) Sin[2 x]
```

Notice that although the multipliers for `E^-x Cos[2 x]` and `E^-x Sin[2 x]` have a complicated form, they still are arbitrary constants.

Comment: J.M. Thanks for your new solution(for me) :) Actually, this question was a exercise when I prepared the **postgraduate entrance examination**  three years ago. The first **built-in** that I know is `DSolve[]`, very glad to know `DifferentialRoot[]` and `FunctionExpand[]` can also deal with this problem.